# How to mute the video using sinch sdk

Tags: sinch, sinch-verification

> How to mute the video using sinch SDK anyone knows please help.
>   After connecting the call I can't mute it.

Comment: Refer here-->https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/muting-calls-use-devices-speaker-ios/

Comment: I am looking for javascript webside code sinch only procide mute option for android & iOs

Answer (score 0):

You can mute/unmute the recipients `<video>` element

```
<video class="remotevideo" id="incoming" autoplay muted></video>
```

Like this:

```
document.getElementById("incoming").muted=false;
```

Muting your own microphone is more complicated issue.
One possible solution is to use Sinch internal instant messaging feature and send a special message to the other end. So instead of muting local microphone you tell the other end to mute remote video.